# How to restrict member creation for different member levels in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Now I have a WordPress installed with simple membership, there are several membership levels: Administrator, A, B, and C.

Level A members only can create members with level B, and level B members only can create members with level C.

I considered to use user role to restrict member creations, but I don't have a clue to create functions for that.

**Update**: I have found out how to do it with the role editor, here is what I did:

In plugin\simple-membership\classes\class.swpm-members.php, there is a line in both functions add() and edit():

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "swpm_membership_tbl WHERE  id !=1 ";
```

After these lines, you can add some rules to filter the level for different member levels. Here is what I added:

```
if (current_user_can('A')) { //A is the name of the role
        $query .= "AND id != 4 AND id != 2";
    }
    elseif (current_user_can('B')){ //B is the name of the role
        $query .= "AND id != 2 AND id != 3";
    }
```

And it's necessary to disable the permission to access user page for these two roles, which can be done by User Role Editor WordPress plugin very easily.